# Select most recent row per item per month

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm looking to create a summary of inventory items, showing the most recent row for each month.

For example, my table has:

```
id, date, item, quantity
```

I'd like to get one row returned per item for each month showing the quantity last reported each month.

Something like:

```
1, (July datetime), Banana, 5
3, (July datetime), Apple, 2
4, (August datetime), Banana, 6
8, (August datetime), Apple, 8
```

Thanks for any help!!

What I've tried so far is this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM inventory t1
WHERE t1.date = (SELECT MAX(t2.date)
             FROM inventory t2
             WHERE t2.item = t1.item)
```

That will, of course, show the most recent row for each item... but not for each month.

Comment: What have you tried? If you don't want to do anything yourself, what is your budget?

Comment: Well, if you want it by month, you need to group by YEAR(t2.Date) and MONTH(t2.Date) in your sub-select. Also t1.date = (sub-select) isn't going to work, I suggest looking into an exists predicate.

Comment: Well it's something like SELECT something FROM yeah whatever

Comment: `akaphenom` practically gave you the entire answer. Just follow the provided instructions.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL `GROUP BY` extension allows you to do it in a following way

```sql
SELECT id, date, item, quantity
  FROM
(
  SELECT id, date, item, quantity
    FROM inventory
   ORDER BY item, date DESC
) q
 GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date), item
```

A more standard way will be to pull MAX date per item per month first and then join back to `inventory` to grab all other fields

```sql
SELECT i.id, i.date, i.item, i.quantity
  FROM
(
  SELECT item, MAX(date) date
    FROM inventory
   GROUP BY item, YEAR(date), MONTH(date) 
) q JOIN inventory i
    ON q.item = i.item
   AND q.date = i.date
 ORDER BY YEAR(i.date), MONTH(i.date), i.item
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56a8f/9)** demo